# Python IDLE (mu-editor) "RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection " Error

Tags: gpiozero

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello():
    print("Hello!")

button = Button(2)

button.when_pressed = say_hello

pause()
```

The above code works nicely in when I run it in the terminal by `python ./button.py`. It also works nicely in mu-editor in the first run in mu-editor. But when I stop the programme in mu-editor and rerun the same script, it prompts the error `RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection`. Am I wrong in some settings?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

[[SOLVED] gpiozero Button - Runtime Error - edge detection - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=226053&p=1387758#p1387758)

> I think I've fixed it in the latest development RPi.GPIO. It turns out
>   that the GPIOs weren't getting cleaned up properly under Thonny and a
>   recent bugfix to RPi.GPIO unmasked the problem.
>
> I will release RPi.GPIO 0.6.5 in the next few days. If you can't wait
>   that long then install the latest development RPi.GPIO (in Raspbian
>   Squeeze):
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
> $ sudo apt-get install mercurial
> $ sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
> $ sudo apt-get remove python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
> $ sudo pip install hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code#egg=RPi.GPIO
> $ sudo pip3 install hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code#egg=RPi.GPIO
> ```
>
> To revert back to the default version in Raspbian:
>
> ```
> $ sudo pip uninstall RPi.GPIO
> $ sudo pip3 uninstall RPi.GPIO
> $ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
> ```